# P8P67LE Motherboard - SATA MODE RAID; Create RAID 1

Tags: raid, raid-1

As it seems my ASUS P8P67LE motherboard has built-in RAID capability.
My OS is previously installed in normal mode and in BIOS setting SATA MODE is set to  AHCI (Advance host controller interface)

Now i want to add 2 HDDs and create a RAID1 only with that 2 HDDs and leave the other HDDs the same as the previous status (no raid)

As i searched, i should go in BIOS setting and set the SATA MODE to RAID (instead of AHCI)
and create a RAID 1 by entering the raid setup( in boot time ctrl+l)
and then i need to revert back the setting to AHCI instead of raid.
Is this ok?
What is the correct approach for my case.

Best Regards

Comment: This is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here. Also, do yourself a favor and don't use the chipset FakeRAID to spare you a lot of pain and sorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the RAID setup - which SATA ports will be acting as RAID1, and which one acting as simple SATA ports, so there could not be a step-by-step guide here, because different RAID-controllers could (and do) have completely different configuration software.

But as it was already told by [SvW](https://superuser.com/users/10961/svw) - **just don't mess with this FakeRAID installation**.

Use software RAID from your operating system - mdadm in Linux or mirroring feature in Windows. You get the same performance (since you don't have dedicated CPU for RAID operations, they end up with you CPU), but get more control and disaster recovery options.